# flutter_form_builder for array of objects

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

How do I get an array of objects using `flutter_form_builder` and `ListView`?
the object:

```
{
  items: [
    {
       id: xx,
       name: xxxx
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have tried:

```
return FormBuilder(
   key: widget.formKey,
   child: ListView.builder(
     shrinkWrap: true,
     itemCount: items.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return FormFieldBuilder(
          child: Row(
            children: [
               FormBuilderTextField(name: 'id'),
               FormBuilderTextField(name: 'name'),
            ]
          )
       );
     }
   )
)
```